# How would I go about Streamlining this code?

Tags: java, javafx

I have been following an online tutorial on how to use JavaFX to create Java Gui programs.

This is one of the programs I made following using the tutorials. I decided to add a counter to the command line which would display the number of orders as well as the customers choices, although I was able to get this working the counter feature looks inefficient.

I feel adding another class to just add the orderNumber variable was wrong.

Is there any advice on streamlining this code?

Also what could I do to output the orderNumber after the Order?

```
public class Main extends Application {

private class Order {
    public int orderNumber = 0;
}

Stage window;
Button button;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Order Number = new Order();

    window = primaryStage;
    window.setTitle("Luke's Sandwich's");

    //Check Box's
    CheckBox box1 = new CheckBox("cheese");
    CheckBox box2 = new CheckBox("Bacon");
    CheckBox box3 = new CheckBox("Tuna");
    CheckBox box4 = new CheckBox("Tomatoes");
    box1.setSelected(true);



    //button
    button = new Button("Order Now");
    button.setOnAction(e -> {
        Number.orderNumber++;
        System.out.println("order: " + Number.orderNumber);
        handleOptions(box1,box2,box3,box4);
    });

    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setPadding(new Insets(20));
    layout.getChildren().addAll(box1,box2,box3,box4,button);

    Scene scene = new Scene(layout,300,250);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();

}

//Handle checkbox options
public void handleOptions (CheckBox box1,CheckBox box2,CheckBox box3,CheckBox box4){


    String message = "user order:\n";

        if(box1.isSelected())
            message += "cheese\n";
        if(box2.isSelected())
            message += "bacon\n";
        if(box3.isSelected())
            message += "tuna\n";
        if(box4.isSelected())
            message += "tomatoes\n";
    System.out.println(message);
}
}
```

Comment: Check out [`FXML`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/jfxpub-fxml_get_started.htm), it allows you to separate interface design and the logic a bit easier.

Comment: Questions about working code should go in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited for CodeReview SE!

Comment: Using a field of `Main` would allow you to accomblish the same...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is *too broad* for Stack Overflow, which is more about *specific* concerns. Code Review would indeed be a better format, but PLEASE make sure you [**read this first**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and that have a title that *describes the purpose of the code* when you post there. Cheers!

Comment: @fabian how do you mean should I use the the "Main" Class to store the Variable

Comment: @Mat's Mug i'll move this thread over to Code Review now I don't use Stackoverflow very often

Comment: Lacking any other use of the `Order` class other than containing a counter for the orders already placed and that class to be limited to a single use per `Main` instance makes placing the field in some designated class unnecessary. -> `public class Main extends Application { public int orderNumber = 0;` can be used and this also cannot lead to reader confusion about the `Order` class being used to store data about an order, like the choice of ingredients...